# In how many ways can $2n+1$ seats in a party are divided among three parties so that the coalition of any two parties will ensure them of a majority?

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can $2n+1$ seats in a party are divided among three parties so that the coalition of any two parties will ensure them of a majority?

If $x$, $y$ and $2n+1-x-y$ are the numbers of seats belonging to the first, second and third party respectively, then the situation in question will be described by the following system of equations:
$$2(x+y)>2n+1$$
$$2n+1>2x$$
$$2n+1>2y$$

Thus the question can be reduced to counting integer solutions of this system. However, I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Please note that somebody included additional information in your question. Next time please do this yourself or the question might be put on hold.

Answer (score 8):

You're looking for the number of solutions in non-negative integers to $$x+y+z=2n+1$$ such that no value is greater than $n$.  From the stars-and-bars formula and the inclusion-exclusion principle, this is $$\binom{2n+3}{2}-3\binom{n+2}{2}=\frac{n^2+n}{2}$$